# unable to tag the ec2 resources boto3 python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I would like to tag the host that I am spining up using boto3 python api

```
response = client.allocate_hosts(
AutoPlacement='on'|'off',
AvailabilityZone='string',
ClientToken='string',
InstanceType='string',
Quantity=123,
TagSpecifications=[
    {
        'ResourceType': 'dedicated-host',
        'Tags': [
            {
                'Key': 'string',
                'Value': 'string'
            },
        ]
    },
])
```

Here is what I am doing

Availability Zone,Instance Type , Quantity are parameterized and I use dictionary to input data

```
            count = 10
            input_dict = {}
            input_dict['AvailabilityZone'] = 'us-east-1a'
            input_dict['InstanceType'] = 'c5.large'
            input_dict['Quantity'] = int(count)
            instance = client.allocate_hosts(**input_dict,)
            print(str(instance))
```

This code works for me but i need to tag the resource too

```
TagSpecifications=[
    {
        'ResourceType': 'customer-gateway'|'dedicated-host'|'dhcp-options'|'elastic-ip'|'fleet'|'fpga-image'|'image'|'instance'|'internet-gateway'|'launch-template'|'natgateway'|'network-acl'|'network-interface'|'reserved-instances'|'route-table'|'security-group'|'snapshot'|'spot-instances-request'|'subnet'|'transit-gateway'|'transit-gateway-attachment'|'transit-gateway-route-table'|'volume'|'vpc'|'vpc-peering-connection'|'vpn-connection'|'vpn-gateway',
        'Tags': [
            {
                'Key': 'string',
                'Value': 'string'
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

how can I input that into the dictionary .. It seems like tag specification has dictionary inside dict .. I am making syntax errors. I tried the below code without success.

```
 input_dict['TagSpecifications'] = [{'ResourceType':'dedicated-host','Tags':[{'key':'Name','Value':'demo'},]},]
```

Comment: Just checking... are you sure that you want to use a **Dedicated Host**? The use-case is normally limited to strange licensing situations where you need control over socket and processor allocations. If you are concerned about other people being on the same host, you can use a **Dedicated Instance**, which is cheaper and easier.

Comment: Yes ...its for licensing use case :)

Comment: What do you mean by "tried the below code without success"? Did you receive an error, or did it simply not tag the host?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to simply pass values directly:

```
response = client.allocate_hosts(
    AvailabilityZone='us-east-1a',
    InstanceType='c5.large',
    Quantity=10,
    TagSpecifications=[
        {
            'ResourceType': 'dedicated-host',
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'Name',
                    'Value': 'Demo'
                }
            ]
        }
    ])
```